# Twilio Method inside of promise does not work

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, twilio

Reading
https://www.twilio.com/blog/implementing-programmable-chat-php-laravel-vue-js
I try implement chat in my Laravel 8 / jQuery 3.5.1 / vue 2.6 app.

This docs has defined :

```
setupChannel(channel){
    let vm = this;
    return this.leaveCurrentChannel()
        .then(function() {
        return vm.initChannel(channel);
        })
        .then(function(_channel) {
        return vm.joinChannel(_channel);
        })
        .then(this.initChannelEvents);
},
```

I want to extend joinChannel method, as I want to make checks if current logged user (laravel auth)
is already joined. I try to make it with promise and failes, as code inside of

```
vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers() is not run. I do 
          setupChannel(channel){
               let vm = this;
                return this.leaveCurrentChannel()
                    .then(function() {
                        return vm.initChannel(channel);
                    })
                    .then(function(_channel) {

                        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                            // debugger

                    

vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers().then(function(users) {
                          // THESE CODE IS NOT RUN.  If to uncomment console and debugging it is not triggered
                            // console.log('++ users::')
                            // console.log(users)
                            // debugger
                            for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                                const user = users[i];
                                console.log('user.identity: ' + JSON.stringify(user.identity) );
                                // console.log('user: ' + JSON.stringify(user, null, 2) );
                                if( user.identity === vm.loggedUser.name ) {
                                    resolve("result")
                                }
                            }

                            debugger // THESE CODE IS NOT RUN
                            resolve("error")
                        })
                        
                    })
                    console.log('++ promise::')
                    console.log(promise) // I SEE this promise in pending state
                    promise
                        .then(
                            result => {
                                alert("result: " + result);
                                return _channel;
                            },
                            error => {
                                alert("error: " + error);
                                return vm.joinChannel(_channel);
                            }
                        )
                    // return vm.joinChannel(_channel);
                })
                .then(this.initChannelEvents);
```

If to run code

```
   vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers().then(function(users)
   ...
```

inside of promise, it works ok and I got valid results.

What is wrong in my promise structure and how can I fix it?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**
I try to follow your way with :

```
joinGeneralChannel() {
    console.log('Attempting to join "general" chat channel...');
    let vm = this;

    if (this.tc.generalChannel == null) {
        console.log('SETTING this.tc.messagingClient.createChannel')
        vm.loadChannelList(vm.joinGeneralChannel);

    }else {
        // console.log('Found general channel:');
        this.setupChannel(this.tc.generalChannel);
    }
},

async setupChannel(channel) {
    let vm = this
    await this.leaveCurrentChannel()
    const newChannel = await vm.initChannel(channel)
    const subscribedUsers = vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers()
    console.log('subscribedUsers::')
    console.log(subscribedUsers)

    let isUserJoined = false
    for (let i = 0; i < subscribedUsers.length; i++) {
        console.log('subscribedUsers[i] ' + JSON.stringify(subscribedUsers[i]) );
        if( subscribedUsers[i].name === vm.loggedUser.name ) {
            isUserJoined = true``
            break
        }
    }
    debugger
    console.log('isUserJoined::')
    console.log(isUserJoined)
```

But in the cosole of my browser I see :

```
Initialized channel General Channel
TeamChat.vue?e1c8:561 subscribedUsers::
TeamChat.vue?e1c8:562 Promise {<pending>}__proto__: Promise[[PromiseState]]: "pending"[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
TeamChat.vue?e1c8:573 isUserJoined::
```

looks like method getSubscribedUsers is asynchronous ?

Thanks!

Comment: I made more checking and debugging I see that all parameters are valid : 
https://prnt.sc/wh8gg3
and 
https://prnt.sc/wh8hfl
I mean that is not problem that invalid variables or invalid scope.
But I do not catch why code inside of
vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers().then(function(users)
does not run. This circle works ok inside of a promise...
Is my promise invalid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your Promise fails, that's why `then()` will never execute. To extend `joinChannel` method you can do something like this with async/await and ES6 syntax:

```
async setupChannel(channel) {
  let vm = this;
  try {
    await this.leaveCurrentChannel();
    const newChannel = await vm.initChannel(channel);
    const users = await vm.tc.messagingClient.getSubscribedUsers();
    const isUserJoined = users.some(({ name }) => name === vm.loggedUser.name);
    const joinedChannel = isUserJoined ? newChannel : vm.joinChannel(_channel);
    return this.initChannelEvents(joinedChannel);
  } catch(err) {
    // if some of promises below will fail, here you'll see details
    console.log('Issue details here:', err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please give a link with quote about getSubscribedUsers?

I found description here :
 https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/sdk-migration-guide-js-10#client-class-changes
 
It says: 
function getSubscribedUsers() returns array of all currently subscribed Users
I did not find any synchronously in it ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong because I found this note in [Android SDK documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/android/sdk-migration-guide-android-10#userinfo-changes) (find on page "getSubscribedUsers")

Comment: Thanks!
Looks like it works ! 
I test it now.
Could you please explain :
1) if all methods in Twilio chat API( at https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/javascript/sdk-migration-guide-js-10#client-class-changes ) are asynchronous?
2) I know what is asynchronous request, like axios, ajax whichhave .then on success. Could you please explain when
promise or await calling must be used? Or good artcle on this issue? That is rather confusing...

Comment: 1. Twilio docs look not really friendly to find something, so I can't say for sure, but you can check [API here](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/index.html) and see what returns each of the methods. For example for [getSubscribedUsers](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/4.0.0/docs/Client.html#getSubscribedUsers__anchor) you can see that's returning `Promise.<Array.<User>>`

Comment: 2. Basically promise and async/await [should be used for async operations](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/34/8e/22/348e225ad4b30681ec5ccf0cbac67736.jpg). This operations "can be fetching data over the internet with Ajax or over WebSocket connections, querying data from a database such as MongoDB or accessing the filesystem with the NodeJs “fs” module", [read more](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee)